# What is the explanation behind not being able to change regional buckets to a multi-region bucket in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage-class-specifier

I understand that the documentation states that multi-regional and regional are not inter-convertible, but fail to see the technical hindrance to it

Comment: Hi @Y.M! Can you accept Brandon Yarbrough solution? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Objects stored in multi-regional buckets are geo-redundant. That is to say, data kept in multi-regional buckets are stored in at least two separate places that are separated by at least 100 miles. Geo-redundancy ensures maximum availability of your data, even in the event of large-scale disruptions, such as natural disasters.

Regional buckets keep multiple copies of your data in one specific regional location. This has performance advantages for data-intensive computations.

Converting a regional bucket to a multi-regional bucket would require moving at least one full copy of the data of the bucket from one location to another. For very large buckets, this transfer would take a significant period of time. It's not currently available as a built-in, instantaneous feature.

Google Cloud does, however, offer a [Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/products/data-transfer/) which can manage moving objects from a regional bucket to a multi-regional bucket.